# Is there any concern about returning generic type object in Dart?

Tags: oop, flutter, dart

I want to implement a different error handling approach in a project without chaining exceptions.
To make it simple as possible, I am tend to write my own basic either-like model.

```
class Either<F, T> {

  final F failure;
  final T value;

  const Either(this.failure, this.value);

  Object check (){
    if (failure != null) return failure;
    return value;
  }

}
```

I am concerning about returning the type Object, is there any problem or considerations with that in Dart or any other language?

Edit:

or returning dynamic type...

```
dynamic check(){
  if (failure != null) return failure;
  return value;   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked over and decided to go with [baihu92's](https://github.com/baihu92/EitherType.git) either_type way. It's much more clear and comprehensible than either in the dartz package. Here is my implementation:

[image]

and the usage is like:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case, it's kind of a wired implementation. The question is, what do you want to do with the actual implementation ? Do you want to replace an `if else` that will appear over and over? In that case, what would you do if you have to handle the error (failure) ? I think a better approach is to use functions as parameters. Here's a short suggestion.

```
class Either<T, F> {
  T value;
  F fail;

  Either(this.value, this.fail);

  void check(success(T value), {failure(F fail)}) {
    if (fail != null && failure != null) {
      failure(fail);
    } else if (value != null) {
      success(value);
    }
  }
}

class SomeClass {
  void checkTheImplementation() {
    Either<String, Error> maybeString = Either("testing", null);
    // if you don't want to handle the error.
    maybeString.check((value) => print(value));
    // if you want to handle the error
    maybeString.check((value) => print(value), failure: (err) {
      print(err.toString());
    });
  }
}
```